# Error creating live broadcast - NodeJS libs

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm trying to create a live broadcast using the nodejs client library but I'm getting the following error:

```
{ Error: Title is required
    at Request._callback   code: 400,
.
.
.
  errors: 
   [ { domain: 'youtube.liveBroadcast',
       reason: 'titleRequired',
       message: 'Title is required',
       extendedHelp: 'https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert#request_body' } ] }
```

It's working on the API Explorer and that's getting me lost with this one. Here is code:

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
var youtube = google.youtube('v3');

var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
  'xxxx', //CLIENT_ID
  'xxxx', //MY_CLIENT_SECRET,
  'http://localhost:3000/api/integrations/youtube'//YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
);

oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  access_token: "xxxx",
  refresh_token: "xxxx"

});

broadcastParams = {
    "auth": oauth2Client,
    "part": "snippet,status,contentDetails",
    "snippet": {
        "title": "Testing NodeJS",
        "scheduledStartTime": "2017-02-20T14:00:00.000Z",
        "scheduledEndTime": "2017-02-20T15:00:00.000Z",
    },
    "status": {
        "privacyStatus": "private",
    },
    "contentDetails": {
        "monitorStream": {
            "enableMonitorStream": true,
        }
    }
};


youtube.liveBroadcasts.insert(broadcastParams,  
function(err,broadcast) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Error creating broadcast: ', err);
    }
    console.log('Broadcast = ' + JSON.stringify(broadcast));
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I opened an bug in the project itself. Here is the follow up link: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/706

Answer (score 2):

Got it solved.

My broadcast parameters wasn't correct. I was missing the "resource". Here is the code that is working now:

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
var youtube = google.youtube('v3');

var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
  'xxxx', //CLIENT_ID
  'xxxx', //MY_CLIENT_SECRET,
  'http://localhost:3000/api/integrations/youtube'//YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
);

oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  access_token: "xxxx",
  refresh_token: "xxxx"

});

broadcastParams = {
    "auth": oauth2Client,
    "part": "snippet,status,contentDetails",
    "resource": {
        "snippet": {
            "title": "Tesing NodeJS 123",
            "scheduledStartTime": "2017-02-20T14:00:00.000Z",
            "scheduledEndTime": "2017-02-20T15:00:00.000Z",
        },
        "status": {
            "privacyStatus": "private",
        },
        "contentDetails": {
            "monitorStream": {
                "enableMonitorStream": true,
            }
        }
    }
};


youtube.liveBroadcasts.insert(broadcastParams,  function(err,broadcast) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Error creating broadcast: ', err);
    }
    console.log('Broadcast = ' + JSON.stringify(broadcast));
});
```